# Resuming a thread and passing in an object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I'm relatively new to threads in java. I was wondering if the following is possible.

- a thread [a] is called (from another object).
- it does some stuff then starts another thread [b] in the same object.
- then it pauses itself and waits for the other thread to finish.
- when it finishes it passes the result of what it's been working on to the paused thread [a] and resumes it.
- the thread [a] then returns the result to the original object that called it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't a do b's work?

Comment: The simple answer is "of course there is" in fact there are a million ways of doing this. Look into the `ExecutorService`, `Semaphore`s, `Thread.join()`, etc.

Comment: Threads run across objects. So in your first step, thread [a] is running and in it, a method on object [x] is called from another object. In the last step, it's the method on object [x] that returns the result to the original object. This is happening in thread [a].

Comment: The reason a doesn't do b's work is that I am programming a chess game and I want the game engine separate to the board separate to the players. This means I could package the engine up and someone else could develop a player object that could be an AI for example. The game engine calls getMove() in the player object which returns the move. If this is from a physical user then the execution of the function would need to be paused until the gui has received the players next move to submit. I hope this makes sense! Please let me know if you can think of a better way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: This can still be a synchronous call, I'd think. Thread [a] can call `getMove()` on someone else's AI object, or from a synchronous user input method. A good reason for a chess game to spawn a thread would be to do some thinking while it is waiting for `getMove()` for the user's answer.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're saying. If the player object was an AI then yes there would be no need for the player object to start a separate thread as there wouldn't be anything to wait for. If it's a physical player though then I think I would need to pause the thread and start a new one like I think you are suggesting. What do you mean when you say 'from a synchronous user input method'? Thanks!

Comment: A synchronous blocking method like `Console.readLine()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

This following example is usually the best way to accomplish the tasks. It does some work in the main thread then passes a `Callable` to an `ExecutorService` which does some work in another thread. The call to `future.get` blocks until the second thread is done and returns the `Object` that the `Callable` returns.

```
private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //do some stuff       
    final Future<Object> future = executorService.submit(new MyOtherWork());
    final Object object;
    try {
        object = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        //handle exception
    }       
    //do some other stuff

}

private static class MyOtherWork implements Callable<Object> {

    public Object call() throws Exception {
        //do stuff in another thread
    }
}
```

Note that as the `ExecutorService` uses non daemon threads by default your application will not exit until it is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your life easier with Threads in java don't use wait(), notify() you will have to use synchronized methods and statements, my suggestion is to use a ReentrantLock and Condition that you pass from the main thread to the secondary threads

[Here you can read more about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

Comment: This looks interesting and I'll remember this for the future. I don't think it has a way to explicitly pass an object back to the original thread though.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) that thread a is waiting to `take()` from and thread b `put()`s its result on?

> Synchronous queues are similar to rendezvous channels used in CSP and Ada. They are well suited for handoff designs, in which an object running in one thread must sync up with an object running in another thread in order to hand it some information, event, or task.

If you want to add timeouts, let thread a `poll()` for the result and thread b `offer()` it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is `java.util.Callable` and `java.util.Executors`.

This is the shortest code that I could write was:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestCallable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        try {
            Integer five = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                    try {
                        return executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {

                            @Override
                            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                                return 5;
                            }

                        }).get();
                    } finally {
                        executor.shutdown();
                    }
                }

            }).get();

            System.out.println(five); // prints 5

        } finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It behaves well. Have you run it? I did. The use of daemon threads is not mandatory.

Comment: I ran it and it definitely does not exit naturally. If you run it from the commandline the prompt never returns.